# CDI interceptor does not work when annotation has parameter

Tags: java, tomcat, annotations, cdi, interceptor

I'm trying to implement a `@Restricted` annotation, to secure controller methods in a way that users can only access them, when they are logged in and have a certain role. I'm on Tomcat 7 using JSF and CDI, so no EJB. The interceptor gets called as long as the annotation interface does not specify any parameters. As soon as I add a `@Nonbinding Role value() default Role.ADMIN;` parameter, neither the interceptor nor the controller method execute. No errors or exceptions either. Here is my code, I really don't know what's wrong with it:

Annotation:

```java
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface Restricted {
    @Nonbinding Role value() default Role.ADMIN; // ###
}
```

Interceptor:

```java
@Interceptor
@Restricted
public class RoleBasedRestrictingInterceptor implements Serializable {
    @Inject
    ISecurityManager security;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object intercept(final InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        final Restricted annotation = ctx.getClass().getAnnotation(Restricted.class);
        log.info("Intercepted, required role is: {}", annotation.value()); // ###
        log.info("User is logged in: {}", security.isLoggedIn());
        return ctx.proceed();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```java
@Named("manageUsers")
@SessionScoped
public class ManageUsersBacking extends implements Serializable {   
    @Restricted(Role.ADMIN) // ###
    public void testRestricted() {
        log.info("testRestricted()");
    }
}
```

The `###` occurrences mark what has to be changed or removed to make it work again. The interceptor is properly defined in `WEB-INF/beans.xml`, since it works without the role parameter in my annotation.

```
16:04:33.772 [http-apr-8080-exec-11] INFO  c.m.s.RoleBasedRestrictingInterceptor - User is logged in: true
16:04:33.772 [http-apr-8080-exec-11] INFO  c.m.c.admin.ManageUsersBacking - testRestricted()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today I revisited this particular problem and noticed it had nothing to do with CDI:

`ctx.getClass().getAnnotation(Restricted.class)`

Obviously, there is no class level annotation in my example. So getAnnotation() returns `null`. Instead I should have used the following:

`ctx.getMethod().getAnnotation(Restricted.class)`

Though I don't know why there where no exceptions whatsoever. Maybe some other things were going on, that I can no longer reproduce because I migrated my application to TomEE.

Comment: Also note that ctx.getClass() returns the class of the InvocationContext, not the class of the target! To get that one, one has to use ctx.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().

Answer (score 1):

if you switch to TomEE you'll don't need to depend (maven) on implementations, just api (use org.apache.openejb:javaee-api:6.0-4 with a provided scope

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have things setup correct (beans.xml and interceptor). Which CDI implementation are you using? If you're using Tomcat have you looked at using TomEE?

Comment: I'm using Weld 1.1.10.Final. I tried to replace Weld with OpenWebBeans (which is the CDI implementation TomEE is using), but there is no documentation on the OpenWebBeans project website (see http://openwebbeans.apache.org/documentation.html, every link is broken). It looks like I need a couple of OpenWebBeans Maven dependencies to use it on Tomcat 7, but without documentation I don't know which ones. If I switch to TomEE, wouldn't I need the same Maven dependencies, but with `<scope>provided</scope>`?

Comment: Yes, you'd have things as provided instead of default or compile.