# @Interceptor Interface with enum Methods returns only default value

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, annotations, cdi, interceptor

I have following case

**Interceptor Interface**

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Documented
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface IErrorHandlerInterceptor {
    Car tyre() default Car.FOUR;
}
```

**Enum class**

```
 public enum Car{
        FOUR,FIVE;
    }
```

**EJB Stateless Class**

```
@ErrorHandlerInterceptor(tyre= Car.FIVE)
public List<?> getCarByName(String name) {
    ----------
    return List<?>;
}
```

**beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation=" http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
   <interceptors>
        <class>de.festado.interceptor.impl.ErrorHandlerInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

**Interceptor Implementation**

```
    @IErrorHandlerInterceptor
    @Interceptor
    public class ErrorHandlerInterceptor {

@AroundInvoke
public Object intercept(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
    IErrorHandlerInterceptor ei = getClass().getAnnotation(IErrorHandlerInterceptor.class);
    String tyresNumber= ei.tyre().toString();
    try {
        return context.proceed();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        ....
    } finally {
        .....
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Now my problem:**

whenever i call `String tyresNumber= ei.tyre().toString();` it just return me the default value which i setted in the interface declaration.

What am i doing here wrong? 
Do i forget something?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer here [CDI interceptor does not work when annotation has parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709203/cdi-interceptor-does-not-work-when-annotation-has-parameter?rq=1) helps me a lot

```
IErrorHandlerInterceptor ei = getClass().getAnnotation(IErrorHandlerInterceptor.class);
```

The  `getClass().getAnnotation(...)`  is wrong. The correct call must come from the context

```
IErrorHandlerInterceptorei = context.getMethod().getAnnotation(IErrorHandlerInterceptor.class);
```