# How add FacesMessage to CDI security interceptor?

Tags: java, cdi

I've created my Security Check by this couple examples:

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709203/cdi-interceptor-does-not-work-when-annotation-has-parameter)

[Blog By Adam Warski](http://www.warski.org/blog/2010/03/simple-security-interceptor-in-weldjsf2/)

But unfortunatly I can't see how to add FacesMesagges exception in case the check fails.

My files:

CheckAction

```java
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface CheckAction {
    @Nonbinding public ESysObject object() default ESysObject.NONE;
    @Nonbinding public EAction action() default EAction.NONE;
}
```

CheckActionInterceptor

```java
@Interceptor
@CheckAction
public class CheckActionInterceptor implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object checkPermissions(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        final CheckAction annotation = context.getMethod().getAnnotation(CheckAction.class);

        if (!isActionAllowed(annotation.object(), annotation.action())) {
            throw new PermissionException("Sorry you don't have needed permissions");
        }

        return context.proceed();
    }
```

MyBean

```java
@Named
@ViewScoped
@Logged
public class PageController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @CheckAction(object = ESysObject.Dictionary, action = EAction.WRITE)
    public String save() {
        switch (action) {
        case "create":
        case "edit":
            service.saveOrUpdate(cursor);
            break;
        }
        return "page?faces-redirect=true";
    }
```

It's all work.

But how to handle PermissionException right? How to `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("security check", new FacesMessage("Permission Error", "you don't have needed permissions"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've done my question.

In my case I've found this ansver:

CheckActionInterceptor

```java
@Interceptor
@CheckAction
public class CheckActionInterceptor implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object checkPermissions(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        final CheckAction annotation = context.getMethod().getAnnotation(CheckAction.class);

        if (!isActionAllowed(annotation.object(), annotation.action())) {
            facesContext.addMessage("Error", new FacesMessage("Permission error", text));
            log.error(text);
            return null;
        }

        return context.proceed();
    }
```

I not thow an error, I return null. And my programm go further, but not permit execute needed action/method.